# Is it possible to show QML controls boundaries?

Tags: qml, qt5

When developing a QML application I think it can sometime be useful if I was able to set some setting to outline all visual elements boundaries. For instance a control in Qt Quick Controls 2.x might consist of several parts like background, contentItem, indicators etc. When tweaking on the size of these I would like to see the boundaries of each of these parts.

Is there any functionality like this in Qt/QML?

Comment: Did you try to define styles for each control and set something like `border.color: "black"; border.width: 5;` ?

Comment: @DuKes0mE: I was hoping for something more generic, for example like QSG_VISUALIZE=overdraw that can be set to show all QML components in 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool called GammaRay which (amongst other things) allows investigating QtQuick 2 applications, see: 
http://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/gammaray-qtquick2-inspector.html

Setup instructions are here:
https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay

If you're running Linux, it is quite likely your distribution already ships a GammaRay package.

Comment: I don't want to be picky, as GammaRay is an excellent tool and free and stuff... Still, IMHO, you should state your affiliation more obvious, than just a *we* and the remark of your employer in your profile.

Comment: @kfunk: I am aware that GammaRay exist, but have not yet used it. From what I can see from the link above it seems like it might do what I want. I will try it out.

Comment: @derM: This is a tool written with FOSS principles in mind, and this is a recommendation solely based on my experiences with it. I'm not paid to go out marketing GammaRay on SO -- that's for sure. I've replaced *we* with *I* so this is more clear.

Answer (score 9):

Three years later, and folks (specifically: me) are still doing web searches about this :)

Just like commenter @DuKes0mE suggested, I have "made do" by adding borders to things on-the-fly and then removing them from the final code.

Like the OP, I am now tired of doing that.

A tactic I arrived at recently is to add a `DebugRectangle.qml` custom element to my project:

```js
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
  property var toFill: parent          // instantiation site "can" (optionally) override
  property color customColor: 'yellow' // instantiation site "can" (optionally) override
  property int customThickness: 1      // instantiation site "can" (optionally) override

  anchors.fill: toFill
  z: 200
  color: 'transparent'
  border.color: customColor
  border.width: customThickness
}
```

Then I can add it to existing elements like so, to debug them:

```js
      Label {
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
      }
      Label {
        text: 'quis nostrud exercitation'
        DebugRectangle {}  // Adds "debug border" to this Label
      }
```

And when I am finished, I can even leave the nested `DebugRectangle` in the code, but toggle its visibility like so:

```js
      Label {
        text: 'quis nostrud exercitation'
        DebugRectangle {
          visible: false
        }
      }
```

[Complete sample project](https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/pull/8/files) shared on GitHub.